# Issue in tagfield component in EXT 5.1

Tags: extjs5

The Tagfield (Multi-select combobox) component throws error when I use grow, growMin and growMax configs in Extjs 5.1.

Please check the following links.

Working in Ext 5.1: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hcg

Not-Working in Ext 5.1: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hch

The same works fine in Extjs 5.0

Answer (score 2):

Sencha apparently knew about this bug and it is already fixed in a nightly build according to this post: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?296899